# Cannot convert value of type 'String?' to expected argument type 'Int64' swift ios

Tags: ios, swift

what causes ther error in the ff. line  and how to resolve itreward: (rewardField?.text) is says that cannot Cannot convert value of type 'String?' to expected argument type 'Int64' swift ios . btw the entity type of reward in code db is int64 .

Thanks

```
  self.saveDataInCoreData(nameOfGroccery: (textField?.text)! , detail: (detailField?.text)! , reward: (rewardField?.text))
  func saveDataInCoreData(nameOfGroccery:String , detail: String , reward: Int64){
    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    let groceryData = GroceryItem(context: context) // Link GroceryItem & Context
    groceryData.name = nameOfGroccery
    groceryData.detail = detail
    groceryData.reward = reward
    groceryData.isSelected = false
    groceryData.houseNo = loggedInUserHouseNumber
    //        print("data:", groceryItem.name)
    (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).saveContext()
}
```

Comment: Try to unwrape the rewardField.text like (rewardField?.text)!

Comment: In your method saveDataInCoreData(), it looks like the data type of reward is Int64, not String.

Comment: i have tried unwrapping it

Comment: yeah exactly its int 64

Comment: The text from a text field is a string even if the string is digits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//if rewardField has some text     and if it can be converted to Int64
guard let value = rewardField?.text, let rewardInt = Int64(value) else {
    /// either no value in rewardField, or value is not Int
    return
}

//OK to proceed now, Call your function
 self.saveDataInCoreData(nameOfGroccery: (textField?.text)! , detail: (detailField?.text)! , reward: rewardInt)
```

Comment: btw sir i would like to ask you how to attach date picker to an alert textfield. like i will select date from a date picker and it the value will reflect to a alert textfield after selecting.

Comment: The amount of exclamation marks in your answer is too damn high!

Comment: the answer addresses the OP's original question. "Cannot convert value of type 'String?' to expected argument type 'Int64' swift ios"
Obviously we should avoid force unwrapping (exclamation) where we are not sure if value exists or NOT

Comment: @DurnKurvirck. text field in alert is no different than oridnary text field. refer to this video to setup a date picker with text field (swift 4 xcode 9) 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QBuYmP2p3AY

Answer (score 1):

Safe way is to use `guard` to check the text is not nil and it can be convert into number.

```
guard let value = rewardField?.text, let reward = Int64(value) else {
    /// Not valid
    return
}
print(reward)
```

It will be invalid in case `rewardField?.text = xyz` (Any non numeric value).

**Edit For Comment**

Always check array count before fetching the element from array. Here as you fetching from `0th` index you can use `first` to fetch first object.

```
if let rewardField = alert?.textFields.first {
   /// Use this rewardField here
   print(rewardField.text)
}
```

Your app might be crash if array doesn't contain any `textField` but by above way will not.

Comment: here is my late version , .. let rewardField = alert?.textFields![0]. and then.  self.saveDataInCoreData(nameOfGroccery: (textField?.text)! , detail: (detailField?.text)! , reward: Int(rewardField!.text))....can you check that and integrate to yours

Comment: @DurnKurvirck Edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

The last parameter in the function saveDataInCoreData has a type Int64.
Please change:

```
self.saveDataInCoreData(nameOfGroccery: (textField?.text)! , detail: (detailField?.text)! , reward: (rewardField?.text))
```

To:

```
self.saveDataInCoreData(nameOfGroccery: (textField?.text)! , detail: (detailField?.text)! , reward: Int64((rewardField?.text)!)!)
```

But, do not use force unwrap, when you init constructor Int64 with a string value, move it to the `if let` or `guard let` statement.

For example:

```
var grocceryTextField: UITextField?
var detailTextField: UITextField?
var rewardTextField: UITextField?

grocceryTextField = UITextField()
grocceryTextField?.text = "a"

detailTextField = UITextField()
detailTextField?.text = "a"

rewardTextField = UITextField()
rewardTextField?.text = "213"

func saveDataInCoreData(nameOfGroccery: String, detail: String, reward: Int) {
    // ...
    print(reward)
}

if let grocceryName = grocceryTextField?.text,
   let detail = detailTextField?.text,
   let reward = rewardTextField?.text,
   let rewardRepresentation = Int(reward) {
     saveDataInCoreData(nameOfGroccery: grocceryName, detail: detail, reward: rewardRepresentation)
}
```

Comment: regarding your advice this is the result -------> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: Yep, because you should move Int(string) to `if let` block.

Comment: can you define it above as an example Sir? @andrew

Comment: Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending String where Int value needs to be passed. You are getting **String** value with **"rewardField?.text"**

You need to convert it into **Int**

You can type change your string value into Int64 with

`Int(rewardField!.text)!`

If you compile your your 64 bit App then you Int will be of 64 bit Itself.

***Note:*** You must validate your textfiled to allow only Int Value or you might get crash for Unwanted values.

Comment: Converting `String` to `Int` is not *type casting* and explicit `Int64` is necessary because Core Data doesn't support regular `Int`.

Comment: how to allow an alert textfield to accept only integer inputs?

Comment: @vadian , cause i am using alerts

Comment: @DurnKurvirck -  change keyboard type to numberpad

Comment: i mean programmatically , making an alert textfield allow only integer inputs

Comment: @vadian - Thank you

Comment: Don't use `!` here what if `rewardField.text` returns alphabets?

Comment: @TheTiger -  Is the reason i told to validate in Note.

Answer (score 0):

The conflict is ... in function parameter list `reward` is an `Int64` type but your argument `rewardField?.text` is a `String?` type  .

Now , all you need is to convert/cast `rewardField?.text` to a 64-bit integer value .