# How can I get a number input from a TextField?

Tags: swift

I will get right to the question.

```
var a = 0 
var b = 20
```

I want a user to input number into `TextField` and I could save that number into variable A. Then I want to do an `if` statement where

```
if a == b {
    //code
}
```

What I am having trouble is getting that number input from the textfield.

Comment: When do you want to get the number from TF on click of a submit Button ?

Comment: yes , under an action button

Comment: is this okay if that TF accepts only Number ? as for this case TF should be accepting number only

Comment: `guard let num = Int(textField.text) else {return} let a = num`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot convert value of type 'String?' to expected argument type 'Int64' swift ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49606290/cannot-convert-value-of-type-string-to-expected-argument-type-int64-swift-i)

Answer (score 0):

You can check the input in the textfield for get the number

**Swift4**

```
let text = textField.text ?? ""
guard let number = Int(text) else {
    print("Must be input the number")
    return
}
// Do your task with number
a = number
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this class Functions

```
class SourceVC: UIViewController
{
    @IBOutlet weak var sampleTF: UITextField!{
        didSet{
            sampleTF.delegate = self
        }
    }
    /// TF value
    var a : Int = 0
    var b : Int = 20

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    /// Assuming this button action to get Value from TF
    @IBAction func naviagteToDestination(_ sender: Any)
    {
        a = Int((sampleTF.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces))!)!

        if a == b {
            print("Execute")
        }
        else{
            print("Dont Execute")
        }
    }
}

extension SourceVC : UITextFieldDelegate
{
    /// This will Limit TF to accept only Numbers
    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool
    {
        let allowedCharacters = CharacterSet.decimalDigits
        let characterSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: string)
        return allowedCharacters.isSuperset(of: characterSet)
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you combine a `guard` with a forced unwrap? That makes no sense.

Comment: Your edit is even worse because now the app will crash if the entered value isn't a valid `Int`.

Comment: But I had used characterset to make sure that entered text in TF is Int Value, still I would like to know how I can make this correct

Comment: See the other answer for one example. Basically, avoid the crash causing forced unwraps.